# Repositioning skill sets on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

Can the skill sets in LinkedIn be repositioned? Because currently users are only able to see the top 6-7 skills sets when visiting a profile for endorsing them.

Answer (score 2):

Top 15 skill sets are based on number of endorsements (higher the number at the top). You can reposition the skill sets which are after the top 15.

- Go to *Profile* → *Edit Profile*.
- Click on the edit icon in *Skills & Expertise*. Then, you can rearrange them by dragging the blocks.

[image]